# Switch In header not showing up properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, mobile

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/Y9ntF/3/

There is no header "bar" and you can obviously see the header is not appearing properly.
How can i fix it?

CSS

```
#myTitle,#myTitle2{
    float:left;
    width:20%;
    margin: .6em 0 .8em 40%;
}
#mySelect,#mySelect2{
    float:right;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

JS

```
$('#myTitle2').append("page title");
```

HTML

```
<div data-role="page" id="defaultevent">
    <div data-role="header" id="ehdr">
        <h1 id="myTitle2"></h1>
        <span id="mySelect2">
            <select name="switch" id="goingswitch" data-role="slider" data-mini="true">
                <option value="off">No Past</option>
                <option value="on">Past</option>
            </select>
        </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding `overflow: hidden` to `#ehdr` is one way:

http://jsfiddle.net/Y9ntF/4/

Answer (score 2):

Another solution is to implement the [clearfix](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/components.html#misc) solution as given in [twitter-bootstrap](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/)

```
.clearfix:before, .clearfix:after {
    display: table;
    line-height: 0;
    content: "";
}

.clearfix:after {
    clear: both;
}
.clearfix:before, .clearfix:after {
    display: table;
    line-height: 0;
    content: "";
}
.clearfix:after {
    clear: both;
}

<div data-role="page" id="defaultevent">
    <div data-role="header" id="ehdr" class="clearfix">
        <h1 id="myTitle2"></h1>
        <span id="mySelect2">
            <select name="switch" id="goingswitch" data-role="slider" data-mini="true">
                <option value="off">No Past</option>
                <option value="on">Past</option>
            </select>
        </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/ZkzGr/)